# "Unknown terminal type" error when trying to run emacsclient

Tags: debian, emacs

(I’m using [emacs23](https://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/emacs23); on Debian 7; Xfce.)

I want to try [Gilles’s recommended solution for taking quick notes with Emacs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2253/60).

When trying to run `emacsclient -a "" -e "(remember-other-frame)"`, I get the following error:

> *ERROR*: Unknown terminal type

**What is wrong?**

---

(Not really sure about what I’m doing,) I tried to start a server from within Emacs: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and entering <kbd>server-start</kbd>. Then it says:

> Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server.
>   There is an existing Emacs server, named "server".
>   To start the server in this Emacs process, stop the existing
>   server or call `M-x server-force-delete' to forcibly disconnect it.

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and entering <kbd>server-force-delete</kbd>, it says:

> Connection file "/tmp/emacs1000/server" deleted

When I now run `emacsclient -a "" -e "(remember-other-frame)"` from a different terminal window (having `emacs -nw` still running in the first one), I get:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
("emacs")
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50a2ps.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50a2ps.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Starting Emacs daemon.
Emacs daemon should have started, trying to connect again
*ERROR*: Unknown terminal type
```

---

### [Edit] Requested information

Output of `echo $TERM; echo $DISPLAY`:

```
xterm
:0.0
```

---

> Are you running this from a terminal emulator, if so which, if not where?

I’m not sure what a "terminal emulator" is, but the *terminal thing* I’m using identifies itself (in the "Info" menu) as: **[Xfce Terminal-Emulator](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/terminal)** (Terminal 0.4.8). It’s the default one that came with installing Debian 7 + Xfce.

---

> What do you have in `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.d`?

- `~/.emacs` does not exist.
- `~/.emacs.d` contains only a sub folder `auto-save-list` (which contains an empty file whose name starts with `.saves`).

Comment: Does `emacs` on its own print the same error?

Comment: @Mikel: I can start `emacs` (opens the GUI) and `emacs -nw` (opens in the terminal) without errors.

Comment: #worksforme. “Unknown terminal type” looks like a bad value for `TERM`, which isn't a common problem unless you've deliberately done something odd. Please post the output of `echo $TERM; echo $DISPLAY`. Are you running this from a terminal emulator, if so which, if not where? What do you have in `~/.emacs` and `~/.emacs.d`?

Comment: @Gilles: I added the requested info at the end of my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Explanation of the bug

`remember-other-frame` calls [`switch-to-buffer-other-frame`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Switching-Buffers.html#index-switch_002dto_002dbuffer_002dother_002dframe-2335)
which calls [`display-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#index-display_002dbuffer-2340) with the variable [`pop-up-frames`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html#index-pop_002dup_002dframes-2357) set to `t`. This results in a call to [`make-frame`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html#index-make_002dframe-2467) with the argument [`pop-up-frame-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html#index-pop_002dup_002dframe_002dalist-2359). The function `make-frame` creates a frame on the same display device as the current selected frame. (What Emacs calls a frame is what GUIs call a window, except that a frame can also be in a text terminal.) At this point, Emacs is still running in daemon mode, so there is no selected frame. Thus `make-frame` sees no GUI environment and thinks it should create a terminal frame, but there is no text terminal either, resulting in the confusing error message “Unknown terminal type”.

#### Simple but clumsy workaround

`remember-other-frame` is the right function to call from within an existing Emacs window, but is technically wrong from emacsclient. There, we should be using the `-c` option to make Emacs create a new frame, and the plain `remember` function.

```
emacsclient -a "" -c -e "(remember)"
```

However this is not very nice because `remember` creates a window which has to be dismissed with `C-c C-c` (which is also what saves the note), then the frame has to be dismissed with `C-x 5 0`. If you forget `C-c C-c` (which is all the more likely because the message to type `C-x 5 0` overwrites the message to type `C-c C-c` in the echo area), the note isn't even saved.

#### A nicer workaround

Instruct `make-frame` explicitly to create the frame on the current X display.

```
emacsclient -a "" -e "
    (let ((pop-up-frame-alist \`((window-system . x)
                                 (display . \"$DISPLAY\")
                                 ,@pop-up-frame-alist)))
      (remember-other-frame))"
```

You can put this all in one line, just make sure not to change the punctuation.

```
emacsclient -a "" -e "(let ((pop-up-frame-alist \`((window-system . x) (display . \"$DISPLAY\") ,@pop-up-frame-alist))) (remember-other-frame))"
```

Comment: If you are struggling with this error using doom emacs (yet), see https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/5438#issuecomment-968357147

Answer (score 3):

If you can call `(make-frame)` directly instead, you can tell it to always create an X frame, which will avoid this error, e.g.:

```
(select-frame
 (make-frame
  '((window-system . x))))
```